# How can I find out how many records are in the list after AngularJS $resource query()

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm struggling with something that I think should be pretty simple.

I want to see how many items are returned from a query() but using length isn't working for me.

This my code

```
    getItems = function () {

        // retrieve the list
        theList = Users.query();
        theList.$promise.then(function (res) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(function (req) {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .finally(function () {

        });

        return theList;
    }

$scope.users = getItems();
console.log($scope.users.length);
```

This is my $resource:

```
.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://example.com/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
})
```

The console shows 0 even if there are items in the list.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where is $resource in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
getItems = function () {

        // retrieve the list
        theList = Users.query();

        theList.$promise.then(function (res) {
            console.log("success");
            $scope.users = res;
            console.log($scope.users.length);
        })
        .catch(function (req) {
            console.log("error");
        });

    }

getItems();
```

Comment: You need to change getItems() to return a promise so you can call .then

Comment: thanks user2085143. this worked.....getItems().$promise.then(function (response) {....}

Comment: Please vote up or mark as the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Just accepted your answer user2085143. Sorry I've been away for a bit....just catching up on all my open questions and giving credit where due!

Answer (score 0):

Your getItem() is returning promise. So extract list from it and then try the length just you did inside your getItem();

```
//try this
getItems().then(function(result) {
    $scope.users = result;
    console.log('result: %o', $scope.users.length);
})
```

Comment: Can you give me some example code? I don't understand your answer - I'm a total noob!